# Facebook share pop with custom content - HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, android, html, facebook

I am trying to create a facebook share pop up with custom text and thumbnail. It works fine on iOS, works fine on desktop but does not display a thumbnail and lastly it does not show any data within it's popup on an android device.

Here is the code I am using. I have used `php` to encode the text first.

```
        <?php
        $title=urlencode('My custom title');
        $url=urlencode('http://www.example.com');
        $summary=urlencode('Some summary text here. Some summary text here. Some summary text here. ');
        $image=urlencode('http://www.example.com/lib/img/fbshare.png');
        ?>

        <a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)"><img src="lib/img/FBshare.png" alt="Share on facebook" title="Share on facebook" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I test this code on desktop and is not working. Seems like facebook actually uses for the title and description of the shared content the meta-tags in the header of the page given in the url parameter. Try this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/